# split parameters and insert values through loop t-sql

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, split

I need to split parameter values delimited by `|` and then I need to insert each of these values into a table

```
SELECT [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AtmRef, '|');

WHILE(@IND != LEN(@STR))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Monitoring (UserId, Name, Surname, Branch, AtmRef, CheckTime, Telephone, Email, DateCreated)
    VALUES (@UserId, @Name, @Surname, @Branch, @AtmRef, @CheckTime, @Telephone, @Email, GETDATE())
END
```

Where `@userId`, `@name` etc are values from the `@AtmRef`. For now `STRING_SPLIT` gives me all values in one column

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML.nodes to split string:

```
DECLARE @AtmRef nvarchar(max) = 'UserId|Name|Surname|Branch|AtmRef|CheckTime|Telephone|Email',
        @x xml

SELECT @x = CAST('<b>'+REPLACE(@AtmRef,'|','</b><b>')+'</b>' as xml)

INSERT INTO Monitoring (UserId, Name, Surname, Branch, AtmRef, CheckTime, Telephone, Email, DateCreated)
SELECT  t.v.value('b[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[2]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[3]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[4]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[5]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[6]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[7]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        t.v.value('b[8]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        GETDATE()
FROM @x.nodes('/') as t(v)
```

You need to use proper datatypes instead of `nvarchar(max)`